# How to send an email with Mailkit

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mailkit

I'm using Mailkit in Asp.net Core to receive email from other but To and From email is the same but in debug To and From have the correct emails?

This is my code what's wrong?/?

```cs
   MimeMessage emailMessage = new MimeMessage() ;
   emailMessage.From.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(_userIdentity.Email));
   emailMessage.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse("my email"));
   emailMessage.Subject = "Support email";

   BodyBuilder emailBodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();
   emailBodyBuilder.TextBody = message;
   emailMessage.Body = emailBodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();


   var smtp = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient();
   smtp.Connect("smtp.gmail.com" , 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
   smtp.Authenticate("my email", "*********");
   await smtp.SendAsync(emailMessage);
   smtp.Disconnect(true);
```

Comment: This may help https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/MimeKit/MimeMessage/-/php-mimemessage-class-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess. You are setting the From address to an address that does not match your @gmail.com address.

When you send the message, the From address gets replaced with your @gmail.com address.

This is because smtp.gmail.com rewrites the From header in order to prevent you from spoofing another person's email address.